# Migrate Core Data from iCloud to local after user signed out from iCloud

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-data, icloud

I have this scenario:

1. an app uses core data with iCloud
2. the user kills the app (it doesn't run even not in the background)
3. after the app killing, the user signs out from the iCloud on the device
4. the user starts the app again, the iCloud account is not there anymore, but the user wants the iCloud data to be there again in local store -> manual migration from iCloud to local non-iCloud store needs to be executed

The question is - is this safe ? Is it safe that the iCloud container and/or data will still be there after the user signs out from the iCloud on the device ? I am talking about scenario that e.g. the user will not be using the app let's say 1 month and in the meantime he signs out from the iCloud.

Thanks
Lubos

Comment: Well the data will still be in iCloud unless he deletes it so when your app starts up it should be able to check that it was last started with an iCloud database and then tell the user they will need to log back in to iCloud in order to get their data base.  This is definitely how things used to work on iOS7 but it is possible this may have been changed - I do seem to recall some WWDC2014 discussion about some changes to allow a last ditched copy to local but have not tested. The docs used to indicate that you should not rely on having access to the iCloud container after the user logs out.

Comment: You mean: 1. in iCloud on the server or 2. in local iCloud store? The question was more about the option 2. I assume that the data are still there in the iCloud on the server (option 1), because the other devices still might need them. But, is also the local iCloud store removed completely - the one in application sandbox ? I checked in the Simulator and it remained there after I logged out. The question is more like if it's safe to rely on it or not after you log in again. If it's not safe, then the user has to restore all the data from the iCloud server after each log out/log in, right ?

Comment: Once the user has logged out of iCloud it is no longer safe to assume the app has access to the local copy of the iCloud store created by Core Data.  Somewhere in the docs Apple explain that they could remove it at any time...  However I do recall there being some mention of some small window being available for you to make a local copy - maybe somewhere in the wwdc2014 material.  In my experience the app immediately looses access, which makes sense from a security point of view.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. That was the info I needed. So basically, there is no way how to get those data to local store without logging into the iCloud again and restoring the data from the server, because the local copy of iCloud might not be there anymore + it is not accessible. Actually, I gave up using Core data + iCloud for now and I am trying out the Ensemble. It has too many corner cases when the issue can occur and all this cases need to be handled properly.